# Json create by JSON.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I need to formate Json as below by using JSON.NET in C#.

```
[
 {"curPage":1,"totalPageCount":12},
 {"t0":171,"t2":"2014-12-25"},
 {"t0":170,"t2":"2014-04-15"},
 {"t0":169,"t2":"2014-04-15"}
]
```

I've already have this

```
List<Record> records = new Record {};
records.add(new Record());

JObject obj = new JObject(
            new JProperty("c",c),
            new JProperty("a",a),
            new JObject(records)
            );
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

class Record {
    public string t0 { get; set; }
    public string t2 { get; set; } 
}
```

And I got "Could not determine JSON object type for type".

How do I deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Paging
{
    public int CurPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPageCount { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int T0 { get; set; }
    public string T2 { get; set; }
}

var lst = new List<object>();
lst.Add(new Paging());
lst.Add(new Item());
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
```